# In pandas, how to concatenate horizontally and then remove the redundant columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframes.

DF1:
col1, col2, col3,

DF2: col2, col4, col5

How do I concatenate the two dataframes horizontally and have the col1, col2, col3, col4, and col5? Right now, I am doing pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis = 1) but it ends up having two col2's. Assuming all the values inside the two col2 are the same, I want to have only one columns.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Dropping duplicates should work. Because drop_duplicates only works with index, we need to transpose the DF to drop duplicates and transpose it back.

```
pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis = 1).T.drop_duplicates().T
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for columns from `DF2` which are not in `DF1` and simple select them by `[]`:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col2', 'col4', 'col5'])


DF2 = DF2[DF2.columns.difference(DF1.columns)]
print (DF2)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col4, col5]
Index: []

print (pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis = 1))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5]
Index: []
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

N = 1000
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N,3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N,3), columns=['col2', 'col4', 'col5'])

DF2['col2'] = DF1['col2']

In [408]: %timeit (pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis = 1).T.drop_duplicates().T)
10 loops, best of 3: 122 ms per loop

In [409]: %timeit (pd.concat([DF1, DF2[DF2.columns.difference(DF1.columns)]], axis = 1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 979 µs per loop
```

---

```
N = 10000:
In [411]: %timeit (pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis = 1).T.drop_duplicates().T)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.4 s per loop

In [412]: %timeit (pd.concat([DF1, DF2[DF2.columns.difference(DF1.columns)]], axis = 1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid duplication of the columns while joining two data frames use the ignore_index argument.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

But use it only if wish to append them and ignore the fact that they may have overlapping indexes

Answer (score 1):

```
DF2.drop(DF2.columns[DF2.columns.isin(DF1.columns)],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Then,

```
pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis = 1)
```